# Issues with VBA code for a range. I'm getting Type Mismatch Error 13

Tags: excel, vba

The code below works for an individual cell, but I get type mismatch when i want to implement this for a range. Would appreciate it if someone can make the below work. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A159:A1034").Value = "SC" Then
        Range("J159:J1034").Value = "SC:NA"
    Else
        Range("J159:J1034").Value = Null
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When would you expect `If Range("A159:A1034").Value = "SC"` to be true? When every cell in the range has that value, or something else? If you need to check the values of lots of cells, you might have to loop through all the values. Setting the values is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Even if `Range("A159:A1034").Value` would work – which it doesn't – it would have to return the value of 875 cells at once. Most likely not what you want.

The easiest way to loop through the range and make the adjustments, would be something like:

```
Dim area As Range, c As Range
Set area = Range("A159:A1034")
For Each c In area
    If c.Value = "SC" Then
        c.Value = "SC:NA"
    Else
        c.Value = Null
    End If
Next c
```

But I do not recommend to use that in a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event for multiple reasons.

First, it will be a pretty heavy operation, which will run each time a change in selection is made. Making the whole worksheet very slow to work with.

Secondly, any cells that does contain "SC" will be changed to "SC:NA", but on next change in selection, they will all disappear. Since they will fail the check and be turned to "Null". This seems like very odd behavior.

IF you want to run it in a worksheet event, you could maybe run it in a `Worksheet_Change` event instead, and limit it to only run as a change in this range is made.

Something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim area As Range, c As Range
Set area = Range("A159:A1034")
If Not Intersect(Target, area) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Value = "SC" Then
        Target.Value = "SC:NA"
    Else
        Target.Value = Null
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

And if you want to trigger a check on the entire range – like the first example, make that a separate sub, that you call as a macro.